# Error: Response not received using IBMCloud VisualRecognition NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I'm follow the getting started's IBMCloud Visual Recognition page: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-getting-started-tutorial&programming_language=javascript#getting-started-tutorial.

The follow code is presented:

```
var VisualRecognitionV3 = require('watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition/v3');
var fs = require('fs');

var visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionV3 ({
  version: '2018-03-19', iam_apikey: '{apikey}'
});

var url= 'https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/visual-recognition/640px-IBM_VGA_90X8941_on_PS55.jpg';

var params = {
  url: url,
};

visualRecognition.classify (params, function (err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
  }
});
```

When I execute it via node on Windows I get the follow error message:

```
error: { Error: Response not received. Body of error is HTTP ClientReque
t
    at formatError (C:\Users\augusto\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-c
requestwrapper.js:111:17)
    at C:\Users\augusto\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\reque
r.js:259:19
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  message:
   'Response not received. Body of error is HTTP ClientRequest object',
```

I've installed alright like the tutorial and I don't know where are the error.

Comment: From the error it looks like there could be an issue with what's inside the get request at the client. Can you add that code too?

Comment: This is the whole code presented by IBM.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```
const visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionV3({
  version: '{version}',
  iam_apikey: '{apikey}'
  disable_ssl_verification: true,
});
```

Comment: ahh so it defaults to HTTPS, they should call that out in the docs.